# Vector Spaces and Subspaces of a System

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am trying to make an example of a 3x5 matrix with a solution set which is a 4d hyperplane.

What I have is a 3x5 where 2 of the columns are linearly dependent. I know that if all of the columns are independent then the solution would be 5 dimensional, so does that mean if 2 are dependent, the solution will be 4 dimensions?

Comment: It’s not possible for a $3\times 5$ matrix to have only two linearly dependent columns.

Comment: "*With a solution set...*" a solution set to what?  The equation $Ax=0$?  The [rank-nullity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem) theorem should help you on your way.  $rank(A)+nullity(A)=n$ for an $m\times n$ matrix.  Now, remember what $rank(A)$ means and is equivalent to (e.g. number of independent columns).

Comment: By “solution,’ do you mean the solution to an equation of the form $A\mathbf x=\mathbf b$, where $A$ is your matrix?

Comment: That is what I mean amd

Comment: The maximum rank would be 3, correct? So the solution would be at most a 3 dimensional hyperplane?

Comment: You have it backwards.  The rank is the dimension of the **image**, not of a solution set.  If all columns are independent, the solution set is of dimension zero.  If you want a four dimensional solution set $\{x~:~Ax=0\}$ i.e. a four dimensional kernel, you want your nullity to be four implying...

Comment: So is it impossible?

Comment: You want your nullity to be four implying that since $rank(A)+nullity(A)=5$ you have $rank(A)+4=5$ implying that $rank(A)=1$.  Is that possible?  Can you come up with an example?

Comment: I would just have 3x5 matrix with one non zero row making the rank(A) = 1, then the number of columns is 5, so 5-1 is 4. correct?